# Starting a python shell with arguments

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal

is it possible to pass arguments to the python in linux without having a file? I'm currently not able to create a file or change permissions and I don't want to write it inside my code like this:

```
import sys
sys.argv = ["arg1", "arg2", ...]
```

I'd like to hand over the arguments while I'm starting the shell:

```
python <arguments>
```

Comment: What would these "arguments" do?

Comment: `python myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3`?

Comment: `python - arg1 args2 …`

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question is about quoting command-line arguments to impact how they are received by `sys.argv` in a script; this question is about passing them *to an interactive REPL session*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While is is questionable if passing commands line arguments to an interactive shell is best practice, it is indeed possible by passing `-` instead of the the scripts file name:

```
$ python - a1 a2
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['-', 'a1', 'a2']
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IPython as interactive shell, you can pass arguments to scripts you run using the `%run` magic command:

```
In [1]: %run myscript.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

(It's not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but you probably want to pass the arguments to some script.)